# Exception saving Java BigDecimal 0.0000001 to oracle using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, bigdecimal

I see an exception when i try to save the the value an entity with a propert having the value new BigDecimal("0.0000001") in to a Oracle table column which has the data type Number (10,7) .
 Other values with the same scale, for example new BigDecimal ("0.0000012") gets saved.

Following is the exception i see

13:56:56,561 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 1438, SQLState: 22003
13:56:56,561 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Comment: This is known as  **the non-representability of 0.1**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: But the value with six decimal places gets saved without a problem BigDecimal("0.000001")

Comment: I don't believe the value 0.0000001 is what is causing your problem.  The key word in your error message is **larger**: 0.0000001 is not too large for your column, so this implies to me that there is something going on in your table that you have not told us about.   For example, does your table have a trigger that calculates the reciprocal of the value in your column?  Please edit your question to include the full stack trace of the exception you see.

Comment: does it work if you store the same value via sqlplus? If JDBC drivers convert BigDecimal to float before storing in into the database, then it is a bug. Maybe try to use another version of drivers. Both BigDecimal and Oracle NUMBER store numbers as decimal digits and there is no need to convert them into floats. Possibly it can also be a bug in Hibernate.

Comment: It allows when i try to save it from Toad

Answer (score 0):

this all works , may be error is caused by some other reason

```
drop table test;

Create table test (
BigDecimal Number (10,7)
);

insert into  test values (0.0000001);
insert into  test values (0.0000012);
insert into  test values (101);
insert into  test values (102);
```